# Drag and drop средствами GWT.

Tags: gwt, java

Проблема такая: у меня есть дерево. Хочу, чтобы пользователь мог перемещать ноды с помощью мыши. Как реализовать dnd с помощью GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, в GWT нет сложностей с dnd. Переопределяете onBrowserEvent - обрабатываете mouse down, mouse move, mouse up. Устанавливаете в sinkEvents - mouse down. Когда наступает это событие добавляете еще mouse move, mouse up, по событию mouse up делаете их unsink. Пока перетаскиваете объект, можете поменять значок курсора или создать специальную PopupPanel, символизирующую перетаскиваемый объект. При перемещении считываете текущие координаты и перетаскиваете эту панельку, напрмиер, так:

```
void move(Event e) { 
  int x = DOM.eventGetClientX(e); 
  int y = DOM.eventGetClientY(e); 
  int w = popup.getElement().getClientWidth(); 
  int h = popup.getElement().getClientHeight(); 
  popup.setPopupPosition(x - w / 2, y - h / 2); 
}
```

Остается только на время перетаскивания запрещать стандартное выделение в браузере!

P.S. Вот [здесь](http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#DragHandleExample95) есть хорошее демо.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, конечно, зависит от конкретной реализации, но в любом случае придётся прикреплять MouseListener и MouseMotionListener.
У MouseMotionListener есть метод mouseDragged.
Я ввёл с глобальные переменные, допустим int StartX и int StartY.
По событию mousePressed им задаются координаты нужного объекта (относительно координат курсора!).
По событию mouseDragged перерисовывается компонент по координатам курсора + Стартовые координаты.
По событию mouseReleased вычисляется к кому ближе всего находится нужный компонент и соответственно задаются ему новые координаты.

Comment: MouseMotionListener и MouseListener к GWT не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Прошу прощения, привычка с AWT